# not able to add headers to response in Angular interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, security, xss, interceptor

I am trying to headers to response using interceptor but it is not adding to response header..Please help me with the solution

intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent> {
console.log("entered into xss interceptor");

```
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
     filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
     tap((event: HttpResponse<any>) => {
       event.headers.append('Content-Security-Policy', "require-trusted-types-for 'script'; default-src 'self'; img-src 'none';style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';") ;
     }),
     );
```

}

Comment: see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-default-headers). You make a clone adding header and execute the next.handle

Comment: return next.handle(req).pipe(
         map((event:HttpEvent<any>)=>{
         if(event instanceof HttpResponse){
           return event.clone({
               headers: event.headers.append('Content-Security-Policy', "require-trusted-types-for 'script'; default-src 'self'; img-src 'none';style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';") 
             });
         }
         
}));
  even after cloning also not able to see response header